# & operator does not do anything in structure?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct BOOK{
    char name[15];
    char author[33];
    int year;
};

struct BOOK *books;
int main(){
    int i,noBooks;
    noBooks=2;
    books=malloc(sizeof(struct BOOK)*noBooks);

    books[0].year=1986;
    strcpy(books[0].name,"MartinEden");
    strcpy(books[0].author,"JackLondon");

    //asking user to give values
    scanf("%d",&books[1].year);
    scanf("%s",&books[1].name);
    scanf("%s",books[1].author);

    printf("%d %s %s\n",books[0].year,books[0].author,books[0].name);
    printf("%d %s %s\n",books[1].year,books[1].author,books[1].name);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I give `1988 theidiot`and`dostoyevski`

the output is

```
1986 JackLondon MartinEden
1988 dostoyevski theidiot
```

in `scanf`, in `books[].name` i used `&`, in `books[].author` I did not use but still it did same. For `year` it did not work. `&` is useless in structure?

I mean here

```
scanf("%d",&books[1].year);
scanf("%s",&books[1].name);
scanf("%s",books[1].author); //no & operator

char name[15];
char author[33];
```

here, i can use

```
char *name[15];
char *author[33];
```

nothing changes. why i cant see the difference?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to understand why & and * operators dont change anything.

Comment: `&books[1].name` and `books[1].name` yield the same address (which is why it works with and without `&`), though the resulting types are slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` member of the `BOOK` structure is a `char` array of size 15. When the name of the array is used in an expression, its value is the address of the array's initial element.

When you take an address of the `name` member from a `struct BOOK`, though, the compiler returns the base address of the `struct` plus the offset of the `name` member, which is precisely the same as the address of `name`'s initial element. That is why both `&books[1].name` and `books[1].name` expressions evaluate to the same value.

Note: you should specify the size of the buffers into which you are going to read the strings; this will prevent potential buffer overruns:

```
scanf("%14s", books[1].name);
scanf("%32s", books[1].author);
```

Comment: what about scanf("%d",&books[1].year);

Comment: @user3122948 `year` is an `int`, so you must take a pointer to it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This form is valid:

```
scanf("%s",books[1].author);
```

This form is invalid:

```
scanf("%s", &books[1].author);
```

`s` conversion specifier expects an argument of type pointer to `char` in `scanf` function, which is true in the first statement but false in the second statement. Failing to meet this requirement makes your function call invoke undefined behavior.

In the first statement, the trailing argument (after conversion) is of type pointer to `char` and in the second statement, the argument is of type pointer to an array `33` of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

When you write

```
scanf("%s", books[1].author);
```

the *expression* `books[i].author` has type "33-element array of `char`".  By the rule above, it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char`" (`char *`) and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you write

```
scanf("%s", &books[1].name);
```

the expression `books[1].name` is an operand of the unary `&` operator, so the conversion doesn't happen; instead, the type of the expression `&books[1].name` has type "pointer to 15-element array of `char`" (`char (*)[15]`), and its value is the address of the array.

In C, the address of the array and the address of the first element of the array are the same, so both expressions result in the same *value*; however, the *types* of the two expressions are different, and type always matters.  `scanf` expects the argument corresponding to the `%s` conversion specifier to have type `char *`; by passing an argument of type `char (*)[15]`, you invoke *undefined behavior*, meaning the compiler isn't required to warn you about the type mismatch, nor is it required to handle the expression in any meaningful way.  In this particular case, the code "works" (gives you the result you expect), but it isn't required to; it could just as easily have caused a crash, or led to corrupted data, depending on the specific implementation of `scanf`.

Both calls should be written as

```
scanf("%s", books[1].name);
scanf("%s", books[1].author);
```

**Edit**

In answer to your comment, a picture may help.  Here's what your `books` array would look like:

```
+---+        +---+
  |          |   |  name[0]                  
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  name[1]
  |          +---+
  |           ...
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  name[14]
  |          +---+
books[0]     |   |  author[0]
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  author[1]
  |          +---+
  |           ...
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  author[33]
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  year
+---+        +---+
  |          |   |  name[0]    <------ books[1].name
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  name[1]
  |          +---+
  |           ...
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  name[14]
  |          +---+
books[1]     |   |  author[0]  <------ books[1].author
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  author[1]
  |          +---+
  |           ...
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  author[33]
  |          +---+
  |          |   |  year
+---+        +---+
```

Each element of the `books` array contains two arrays plus an integer.  `books[1].name` evaluates to the address of the first element of the `name` array within `books[1]`; similarly, the expression `books[1].author` evaluates to the address of the first element of the `author` array within `books[1]`.

Comment: but it is not first element of books[] array, the second element, books[1]?